# React native agora integration Problem. After install agora sdk in my project the project is not build

Tags: react-native, agora.io

After install react-native-agora project is not build.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rerW8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add this activity tag in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag

```
<activity android:name="io.agora.rtc.ss.impl.ScreenSharing$LocalScreenCaptureAssistantActivity" android:exported="false" tools:node="merge" />

<service android:name="io.agora.rtc.ss.impl.LocalScreenSharingService" android:exported="false" android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" tools:node="merge" />
```